# Matrix is too tall and too thin

Tags: matrices

As part of my Linear Algebra homework I have to draw some matrices. However, I find the matrices generated by a `pmatrix` environment too small and too thin. The matrices in the docs my prof uploaded look way better in my opinion, so I was wondering how I could get that result. I can't use math mode as I need the matrices inline (they were also inline in my prof's docs).

Pics and code attached, the matrix I generated is the upper one.

[image: My matrix]

[image: my prof's matrix]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
2\\
3
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't produce anything that comes close to either of images of column vectors you've posted. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. Have you maybe modified the `\arraystretch` parameter? If so, what's its value?

Comment: Also, your example is using inline math, so I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to use math mode inline.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Comment: You can add `\ ` or other space comands on each side of  any column.  Most authors are trying to cram as much math into a small space as possible.

Comment: the code you show [produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMGJ.png) which does not match what you show, but I would guess the other output is from `\left(\begin{array}` rather than `\begin{pmatrix}`

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce your picture, which is admittedly ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `\doublespacing` (but you shouldn't unless forced by some antiquated regulation), you need to correct `\arraystretch` to be the reciprocal of `\baselinestretch`, in this case `0.6`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more separation with the parentheses, you can use `array`. My opinion is that it's impossible to have good looking parentheses at large sizes, but yours may differ. I always use brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{array}\right)
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The one on the left is too spaced out and doesn't look good (your teacher seems to think differently or is unaware of `pmatrix`). Of course my advice is to not use `\doublespacing`.